# (1) Design of ASCII codes and (2) logical operator which results in negative number

Tags: assembly, ascii, logical-operators

There are two basic and simple assembly question which I cannot understand them and didn't find any answer for them.... So I don't know what to answer if somebody ask me!

**Major question:**

1) Why ASCII designers used 30-39 codes for decimal numbers 0-9? It is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) that the  first 30 codes are reserved for control operations (which are non printable characters). With their design, we have to manipulate and remove the first 3. If they assigned 0-9 codes for decimal numbers I think it was better!!

**Minor question**

2) What is the interpretation of a negative number as a result of OR instruction? As you know, OR can alter SF bit. For example:

```
 0010  1100
 1011  1011  OR
-------------
 1011  1111      => SF=1 => negative number
```

But we see `2C OR BB = BF`. So what does negative mean here? I don't see any negative value here! Isn't a misunderstanding?

Comment: `SF` just means that the leftmost bit is set. That indicates a negative value for signed numbers and means nothing for unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why ASCII designers used 30-39 codes for decimal numbers 0-9?

The number characters are actually encoded with ASCII numbers [48,57]. You should specify a suffix when dealing with hexadecimal values [30h,39h].

> It is stated here that the first 30 codes are reserved for control operations (which are non printable characters)

What about this **30** ?

- If you mean 30 decimal then you're missing 2 control characters (ASCII's 30 and 31).
- If you mean 30h then you're mistaken because characters [20h,2Fh] are indeed printable.

> But we see 2C OR BB = BF. So what does negative mean here? I don't see any negative value here! Isn't a misunderstanding?

The resulting number BFh is a negative number. It has its highest bit on.

Comment: I said, why they didn't assign 00H to 00 (decimal) and so on.... why they started from 30 and then stated to remove 3

Comment: That's a __what came first problem__. Those control codes existed before the well-known ASCII set was agreed upon.